# Dúvida consulta no SQL Server - Associação de Informações

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Meus caros, boa noite! Estou precisando realizar uma consulta em um banco de dados utilizando SQL Server e fiquei empacado em um problema por isso peço, por favor a ajuda de vocês.

Segue um resumo exemplificativo do problema:

- Tenho uma tabela que contém o nome de pessoas (chamarei de TABELA 1);
- Tenho uma tabela que agrupa certas pessoas da TABELA 1 e estabelece quem é a pessoa principal e quem são as secundárias desse agrupamento (chamarei de TABELA 2);

A TABELA 1 é mais ou menos assim:

```
IdP   Nome
1    João
2    Maria
3    José
```

A TABELA 2 é mais ou menos assim:

```
IdG  IdP  Prcp
1    1    1
1    2    0
1    3    0
```

Ou seja, neste exemplo, as 3 pessoas estão agrupadas no mesmo grupo e João é o principal e os demais são secundários... Eu gostaria de construir uma consulta que retornasse:

```
Nome   NomePrincipal
João   João
Maria  João
José   João
```

Eu tentei a consulta a seguir, mas sem sucesso:

```
select T1.Nome as 'Nome', T1P.Nome as 'NomePrincipal' from TABELA2 T2
inner join TABELA1 T1 on T2.IdP = T1.IdP
left join TABELA1 T1P on T2.IdP = T1P.IdP AND T2.Prcp = 1
```

Estou obtendo o seguinte resultado:

```
Nome   NomePrincipal
João   João
Maria  NULL
José   NULL
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9a09c/3

A DDL abaixo é opcional,

```
CREATE TABLE Tabela1
(
  IdP INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Nome NVARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Tabela2
(
  IdG INT NOT NULL,
  IdP INT NOT NULL,
  Prcp INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY PK_Tabela2 (IdG, IdP),
  FOREIGN KEY FK_Tabela2_Tabela1 (IdP) REFERENCES Tabela1 (IdP)
)
GO
```

A DML para reproduzir o conteúdo da base de dados é opcional, também,

```
INSERT INTO Tabela1 VALUES (1, 'João')
GO
INSERT INTO Tabela1 VALUES (2, 'Maria')
GO
INSERT INTO Tabela1 VALUES (3, 'José')
GO

INSERT INTO Tabela2 VALUES (1, 1, 1)
GO
INSERT INTO Tabela2 VALUES (1, 2, 0)
GO
INSERT INTO Tabela2 VALUES (1, 3, 0)
GO
```

Segue a DML:

```
SELECT t1.Nome, t1a.Nome Principal
FROM Tabela1 t1
JOIN Tabela2 t2 ON t2.IdP = t1.IdP
JOIN Tabela2 t2a ON t2a.IdG = t2.IdG AND t2a.Prcp = 1
JOIN Tabela1 t1a ON t1a.IdP = t2a.IdP
GO
```

Obs.: o *fiddle* está feito no MySQL porque, aparentemente, o SQL Server 2017 disponível no site estava em manutenção.